# Onclick applied on many elements, firing on second click

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

I've made a little accordion-like script. Technically it works, but on the second click. How to fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/YcEjF/

```
<ul>
    <li>chapter 1</li><span>lorem ipsum</span>
    <li>chapter 2</li><span>lorem ipsum</span>
    <li>chapter 3</li><span>lorem ipsum</span>
    <li>chapter 4</li><span>lorem ipsum</span>
    <li>chapter 5</li><span>lorem ipsum</span>
</ul>

var a = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].onclick = function() {
        var st = this.nextSibling.style;
        if (st) {
            st.display = (st.display == "none" ? "block" : "none");
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`st.display` starts out empty because it's set in CSS and not in an inline style. There are three ways to fix this.

(1) Explicitly set the style in javascript ahead of time:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].nextSibling.style.display = 'none';      // <-- Added this line
    a[i].onclick = function() {
        var st = this.nextSibling.style;
        if (st) {
            st.display = (st.display == "none" ? "block" : "none");
        }
    };
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YcEjF/1/

(2) Test on "block" instead of "none", reversing the comparison, but otherwise using the same method:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].onclick = function() {
        var st = this.nextSibling.style;
        if (st) {
            st.display = (st.display == "block" ? "none" : "block");
        }
    };
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YcEjF/2/

(3) Explicitly set the style tags instead of using css. So leave your javascript the same but change your html, like so:

```
<ul>
    <li>chapter 1</li><span style="display: none;">lorem ipsum</span>
    ...
</ul>
```

And remove that `display: none;` from the css:

```
span { margin: 15px; }​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YcEjF/3/

Answer (score 1):

When you click first time a sibling element style is empty `st.display == ""`, you should handle this behavior:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].onclick = function() {
        var st = this.nextSibling.style;
        if (st) {
            // Updated condition: added st.display == ""
            st.display = (st.display == "none" || st.display == "" ? "block" : "none");
        }
    };
}​
```

If you have a jQuery library, you can use this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/YcEjF/4/) to make script simpler:

```
$('li').toggle(function(){
  $(this).next().attr('style', 'display: block;');
},function(){
  $(this).next().attr('style', 'display: none;');
})​
```

P.S. By the way it's not a good practice to use `<span>` elements instead of `<li>`. The better way looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YcEjF/29/) or you can rename `<span>` elements to `<li>`.